# Missing table error after moving to Hibernate 5.2

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, naming

After upgrading hibernate to version 5.2.10 i'm getting following error on my Spring Boot (1.4) application:

**Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [abc.DummyPojoClass]**

Java class is like:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "abc", name = "DummyPojoClass")
public class DummyPojoClass  {

    @Column(name = "object_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long objectId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Value
    private String name;
}
```

In database table is abc.dummypojoclass, and on Hibernate 4.3 there was no problem with resolving table name. I tried to change naming strategy setting in app.properties this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

But it didn't help. Any ideas how to solve issue?

Comment: Can you try putting name = "DummyPojoClass" to name = "dummypojoclass" in the @Table annotation

Answer (score 0):

`PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` does nothing. You can extend that strategy and convert table names to lowercase.

```
public class LowerCasePhysicalNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return context.getIdentifierHelper()
                .toIdentifier(name.getText().toLowerCase());
    }

}
```

Probably, you will need to change this strategy, if you need something besides a conversion to lowercase.

Comment: So what has changed in Hibernate 5.x, this worked fine with version 4.3?

Comment: @bojek if you didn't use any naming strategy for Hibernate 4 — nothing (except names of constraints).